# Eclipse #ifdef error using JNI, Android NDK and Vuforia

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface, eclipse-cdt, vuforia

With Vuforia's ImageTargets sample application, I tried using OpenGL ES 1.1 by setting USE_OPENGL_ES_1_1 to true in jni/Android.mk and uncommenting and changing the corresponding line in AndroidManifest.xml (). After converting the project so that it has a C++ perspective and associating ndk-build and the proper include directories, I could successfully run the application on my Android device.

However, the problem is that once I open up jni/ImageTargets.cpp, I get several errors from Eclipse, all from places where OpenGL ES 2.0 code would execute, the first one being:

> Description Resource Path Location Type Symbol 'vertexHandle' could
>   not be resolved ImageTargets.cpp /ImageTargets/jni line 402 Semantic
>   Error

Sure enough, vertexHandle is defined at the top of the ImageTargets.cpp, inside the "#ifdef USE_OPENGL_ES_2_0" block. Because USE_OPENGL_ES_2_0 is not defined (per Android.mk), the code should be able to compile successfully, and sure enough, ndk-build does not report any problems. So it seems that only Eclipse reports the problems and when I run the project, Eclipse says, "Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application." And thus, I cannot run my application anymore. In a sense, it's kind of strange that this never occurred until I opened ImageTargets.cpp and Eclipse "discovered" the errors.

The best work-around I've found so far is to just delete or comment out those lines (that should not be causing problems because USE_OPENGL_ES_2_0 is not supposed to be defined)... Is there a better way to deal with this problem? Did I miss a setting in Eclipse that should solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution: go to the project properties -> C/C++ Build -> Discovery Options -> Check "Automate discovery of paths and symbols"